# How to get geometry information of a single wall?

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I want to retrieve geometry information from a single wall in  IFC file. 
I have tried it using Xbim. I have learned that XbimModel.GetGeometryData Method (IfcProduct, XbimGeometryType) could be used to obtain information of a single ifc element.But this method seems to be obsoleted now. My question is  how to get geometry information,say,the vertex coordination of a single ifc wall?

Answer (score 0):

There are diffrent ways to get the Informations. In generall you ned to get the selected IFC Element. If you got that you are able to read all the informations you want.

If use for example `XbimWebUI` you can get all your infos from the `viewer`.